# Arduino time between interrupts in POV led display

Tags: led, time

I'm making a POV display (4 spokes) on a bike wheel using a Hall effect sensor to measure how long the last revolution took and based on that I calculate delays in the display. By pedalling at a constant rate I should get roughly a nice image but all I got is an unsynchronized mess. It seems like it is going and image is stable but after around half of a turn it scrambles.

I divided the wheel into 32 even parts which uses the same LED colour. Any advice how to achieve full synchronization. Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
#include "Adafruit_WS2801.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#ifdef __AVR_ATtiny85__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MIN_TIME 150000
#define MAX_TIME 1000000
#define RADIUS 240
#define MAGNETS_NUM 1
uint8_t shwFg = 1;
uint8_t dataPin1  = 2; // White wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin2  = 3; // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin3  = 4; // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin4  = 5; // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin1 = 10; // White wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin2 = 11; // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin3 = 12; // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin4 = 13; // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t hallPin  = 20;
uint8_t pointer1 = 0;
uint8_t pointer2 = 8;
uint8_t pointer3 = 16;
uint8_t pointer4 = 24;
uint8_t LED1R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED2R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED3R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED4R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED5R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED6R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED7R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED8R[32] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 144, 144, 144};
uint8_t LED1B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED2B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED3B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED4B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED5B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED6B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED7B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED8B[32] = {128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1, 128, 128, 128, 128, 1, 1, 1, 1};
uint8_t LED1G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED2G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED3G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED4G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED5G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED6G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED7G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
uint8_t LED8G[32] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
long now = 0;
long prev = 0;
int hallState = 0;
unsigned long previous = 0;
unsigned long dlyMic = 123456;
Adafruit_WS2801 strip = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin1, clockPin1);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip2 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin2, clockPin2);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip3 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin3, clockPin3);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip4 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin4, clockPin4);
int a = 0;
unsigned long current = 0;
unsigned long  delta = 0;

void GetDelay() {
  previous = current;
  current = micros();
}

void setup() {
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif
  pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  strip.begin();
  strip2.begin();
  strip3.begin();
  strip4.begin();
  attachInterrupt(3, GetDelay, HIGH);
}

void delayMicroseconds2(unsigned int us) {
  // calling avrlib's delay_us() function with low values (e.g. 1 or
  // 2 microseconds) gives delays longer than desired.
  //delay_us(us);
  // for the 16 MHz clock on most Arduino boards
  // for a one-microsecond delay, simply return.  the overhead
  // of the function call yields a delay of approximately 1 1/8 us.
  if (--us == 0) return;
  // the following loop takes a quarter of a microsecond (4 cycles)
  // per iteration, so execute it four times for each microsecond of
  // delay requested.
  us <<= 2;
  // account for the time taken in the preceeding commands.
  us -= 2;
  // busy wait
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "1: sbiw %0,1" "\n\t" // 2 cycles
    "brne 1b" : "=w" (us) : "0" (us) // 2 cycles
  );
}

void loop() {
delta  = current - previous;
delta<<5;
delta-=6800; //time required for loop

  if (shwFg == 0) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
      strip3.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
      strip4.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
  } else {
    strip.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer1] , (LED1B[pointer1] ) , (LED1G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer2] , (LED1B[pointer2] ) , (LED1G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer3] , (LED1B[pointer3] ) , (LED1G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer4] , (LED1B[pointer4] ) , (LED1G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer1] , (LED2B[pointer1] ) , (LED2G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer2] , (LED2B[pointer2] ) , (LED2G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer3] , (LED2B[pointer3] ) , (LED2G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer4] , (LED2B[pointer4] ) , (LED2G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer1] , (LED3B[pointer1] ) , (LED3G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer2] , (LED3B[pointer2] ) , (LED3G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer3] , (LED3B[pointer3] ) , (LED3G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer4] , (LED3B[pointer4] ) , (LED3G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer1] , (LED4B[pointer1] ) , (LED4G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer2] , (LED4B[pointer2] ) , (LED4G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer3] , (LED4B[pointer3] ) , (LED4G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer4] , (LED4B[pointer4] ) , (LED4G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer1] , (LED5B[pointer1] ) , (LED5G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer2] , (LED5B[pointer2] ) , (LED5G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer3] , (LED5B[pointer3] ) , (LED5G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer4] , (LED5B[pointer4] ) , (LED5G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer1] , (LED6B[pointer1] ) , (LED6G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer2] , (LED6B[pointer2] ) , (LED6G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer3] , (LED6B[pointer3] ) , (LED6G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer4] , (LED6B[pointer4] ) , (LED6G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer1] , (LED7B[pointer1] ) , (LED7G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer2] , (LED7B[pointer2] ) , (LED7G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer3] , (LED7B[pointer3] ) , (LED7G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer4] , (LED7B[pointer4] ) , (LED7G[pointer4] ) );
    strip.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer1] , (LED8B[pointer1] ) , (LED8G[pointer1] ) );
    strip2.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer2] , (LED8B[pointer2] ) , (LED8G[pointer2] ) );
    strip3.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer3] , (LED8B[pointer3] ) , (LED8G[pointer3] ) );
    strip4.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer4] , (LED8B[pointer4] ) , (LED8G[pointer4] ) );
  }
  strip.show();
  strip2.show();
  strip3.show();
  strip4.show();

  pointer1++;
  pointer1 &= 31;
  pointer3++;
  pointer3 &= 31;
  pointer2++;
  pointer2 &= 31;
  pointer4++;
  pointer4 &= 31;
  delayMicroseconds2(delta);

}
```

Pardon me, it was late in the night and I put wrong code. Of course delay should depend on delta. Changed to newest code with less job in delay. Still yields similar results.

Comment: `dlyMic` Should be defined as "volatile". Your delays don't take into account that all the code inside the loop takes some time to ru   Especially strip.show.

Comment: How much memory (RAM) does this sketch require?

Comment: @Gerben Nice found I think it is fixed now but still a bit still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @MikaelPatel Not much about 1024 bytes, 12% of megas dynamic memory and 2% od program memory.

Comment: To the "anonymous user" who continually attempts to make edits to this question. Please create an account on Arduino SE, so that we can see who is making the edits. If you are the OP, who posted the question on SE Electronics, please login to SE Arduino, using your SE Electronics ID (SE Arduino will simply be added to your existing account) - that way your edits will no longer keep on being rejected.

Comment: @Herioz - if you want to modify your question please do it as yourself (Herioz) and not as an anonymous user (ie. not logged in). That way the changes are recognized as yours and not someone else trying to change the sense of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, `dlyMic` should be declared as a `volatile` variable.  This is true of any variables where `loop()` gets a value changed by an interrupt service routine, or where it puts a value for the ISR to use.  In either case, if the variable is multibyte, you may wish to surround the get or put by code to turn interrupts off and on, to avoid race conditions where the ISR is reading or changing a value coincidentally with `loop()` changing or reading it.  For example:

```
byte statusReg = SREG; // Save interrupt status
cli();                 // Turn off interrupts
++somethingimportant;  // Need interrupts off for atomicity
SREG = statusReg;      // Restore old status
```

Aside from that, your treatment of `dlyMic` resembles a bad random number generator.  It consists of a declaration line; a couple of lines in the ISR; and use as a delay parameter in `loop()`:

```
unsigned long dlyMic =123456;
...

  dlyMic<<5;
  dlyMic-=6500;
...
delayMicroseconds2(dlyMic);
```

The following two lines of Python compute the series of numbers that will result as values of `dlyMic`.

```
dlyMic=123456; mk = 2**32-1
for i in range(14): print dlyMic; dlyMic=(dlyMic*32-6500)&mk
```

They produce:

```
123456
3944092
126204444
4038535708
384117276
3701811740
2493852188
2493852188
2493852188
...
```

You may wish to connect up your `dlyMic` calculations with your measurement, `delta`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code was from a [rejected suggested edit](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22215), by an anonymous user, to the original post. See also [Rejected edit results in loss of constructive code modification](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/rejected-edit-results-in-loss-of-constructive-code-modification).

I have reproduced the code here - it may be of some use to someone:

```
#include "Adafruit_WS2801.h"
#include "SPI.h" // Comment out this line if using Trinket or Gemma
#ifdef __AVR_ATtiny85__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



#define MIN_TIME 150000
#define MAX_TIME 1000000
#define RADIUS 240
#define MAGNETS_NUM 1
uint8_t shwFg = 1;
uint8_t dataPin1  = 2;    // White wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin2  = 3;    // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin3  = 4;    // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t dataPin4  = 5;    // Yellow wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin1 = 10;    // White wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin2 = 11;    // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin3 = 12;    // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t clockPin4 = 13;    // Green wire on Adafruit Pixels
uint8_t hallPin  = 20;
uint8_t pointer1 =0;
uint8_t pointer2 =8;
uint8_t pointer3 =16;
uint8_t pointer4 =24;

int addr = 0;

uint8_t LED1R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED2R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED3R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED4R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED5R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED6R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED7R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED8R[32] = {128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

uint8_t LED1B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED2B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED3B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED4B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED5B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED6B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED7B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};
uint8_t LED8B[32] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128};


uint8_t LED1G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED2G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED3G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED4G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED5G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED6G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED7G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t LED8G[32] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};


long now = 0;
long prev =0;
int hallState = 0;
unsigned long previous = 0;
unsigned long dlyMic =123456;

Adafruit_WS2801 strip = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin1, clockPin1);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip2 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin2, clockPin2);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip3 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin3, clockPin3);
Adafruit_WS2801 strip4 = Adafruit_WS2801((uint16_t)8, dataPin4, clockPin4);



int a = 0;
unsigned long current=0;
unsigned long  delta=0;
void GetDelay() {
  previous = current;
  current = micros();


//  previous = micros();

}

void setup() {
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif

 pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);
 Serial.begin(115200);

  strip.begin();
  strip2.begin();
  strip3.begin();
  strip4.begin();
  attachInterrupt(3, GetDelay, RISING);

}
void delayMicroseconds2(unsigned int us)
{
        // calling avrlib's delay_us() function with low values (e.g. 1 or
        // 2 microseconds) gives delays longer than desired.
        //delay_us(us);
        // for the 16 MHz clock on most Arduino boards

        // for a one-microsecond delay, simply return.  the overhead
        // of the function call yields a delay of approximately 1 1/8 us.
        if (--us == 0)
                return;

        // the following loop takes a quarter of a microsecond (4 cycles)
        // per iteration, so execute it four times for each microsecond of
        // delay requested.
        us <<= 2;

        // account for the time taken in the preceeding commands.
        us -= 2;

        // busy wait
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
                "1: sbiw %0,1" "\n\t" // 2 cycles
                "brne 1b" : "=w" (us) : "0" (us) // 2 cycles
        );
}
void loop() {
 // prev = micros();
  //    noInterrupts();

  delta  = current - previous;

  if (delta > MAX_TIME) {
    shwFg = 0;
  }else{
    shwFg = 1;
  }

  shwFg = 1;
  delta<<1;
  delta-=650;

    if (shwFg == 0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
          strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
          strip2.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
          strip3.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
          strip4.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    else {

      strip.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer1] ,(LED1B[pointer1] ) ,(LED1G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer2] ,(LED1B[pointer2] ) ,(LED1G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer3] ,(LED1B[pointer3] ) ,(LED1G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(0, LED1R[pointer4] ,(LED1B[pointer4] ) ,(LED1G[pointer4] ) );

      strip.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer1] ,(LED2B[pointer1] ) ,(LED2G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer2] ,(LED2B[pointer2] ) ,(LED2G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer3] ,(LED2B[pointer3] ) ,(LED2G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(1, LED2R[pointer4] ,(LED2B[pointer4] ) ,(LED2G[pointer4] ) );


      strip.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer1] ,(LED3B[pointer1] ) ,(LED3G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer2] ,(LED3B[pointer2] ) ,(LED3G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer3] ,(LED3B[pointer3] ) ,(LED3G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(2, LED3R[pointer4] ,(LED3B[pointer4] ) ,(LED3G[pointer4] ) );


      strip.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer1] ,(LED4B[pointer1] ) ,(LED4G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer2] ,(LED4B[pointer2] ) ,(LED4G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer3] ,(LED4B[pointer3] ) ,(LED4G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(3, LED4R[pointer4] ,(LED4B[pointer4] ) ,(LED4G[pointer4] ) );


      strip.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer1] ,(LED5B[pointer1] ) ,(LED5G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer2] ,(LED5B[pointer2] ) ,(LED5G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer3] ,(LED5B[pointer3] ) ,(LED5G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(4, LED5R[pointer4] ,(LED5B[pointer4] ) ,(LED5G[pointer4] ) );


      strip.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer1] ,(LED6B[pointer1] ) ,(LED6G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer2] ,(LED6B[pointer2] ) ,(LED6G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer3] ,(LED6B[pointer3] ) ,(LED6G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(5, LED6R[pointer4] ,(LED6B[pointer4] ) ,(LED6G[pointer4] ) );


      strip.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer1] ,(LED7B[pointer1] ) ,(LED7G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer2] ,(LED7B[pointer2] ) ,(LED7G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer3] ,(LED7B[pointer3] ) ,(LED7G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(6, LED7R[pointer4] ,(LED7B[pointer4] ) ,(LED7G[pointer4] ) );

      strip.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer1] ,(LED8B[pointer1] ) ,(LED8G[pointer1] ) );
      strip2.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer2] ,(LED8B[pointer2] ) ,(LED8G[pointer2] ) );
      strip3.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer3] ,(LED8B[pointer3] ) ,(LED8G[pointer3] ) );
      strip4.setPixelColor(7, LED8R[pointer4] ,(LED8B[pointer4] ) ,(LED8G[pointer4] ) );
   }

    strip.show();
    strip2.show();
    strip3.show();
    strip4.show();
    //delay(10);
    pointer1++;
    pointer1&=31;

    pointer3++;
    pointer3&=31;

    pointer2++;
    pointer2&=31;

    pointer4++;
    pointer4&=31;
  //       interrupts();
   // now =micros();
    delayMicroseconds2(delta);


  //Serial.println(now - prev);

}
```

Comment: There is [another rejected edit here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22263).